# Show data per weekday for this week and the week prior

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to create a clustered bar chart, that displays the number of calls recieved for each weekday for this week, and the week prior. After several days of trial and error, I have still not gotten it to work properly.

I would like the bar chart to sort dynamicly depending on the current day (or yesterday, as my data is always 1 day behind). So, if today is Friday the right most column should be Thursday, and the left most column should be Friday. With each weekday having 2 columns. 1 for the [Call Count] of the latest weekday, and one for the [Call Count] of the same weekday before that. My data is connected as a Cube, and my calendar table is created as below:

```
Calendar = 
VAR StartDate = DATE(2023, 11, 1)
VAR EndDate = TODAY() - 1
RETURN
ADDCOLUMNS (
    CALENDAR(StartDate, EndDate),
    "DateTypeKey", FORMAT( [Date], "YYYY-MM-DD" ),
    "DateAsInteger", INT( FORMAT( [Date], "YYYYMMDD" ) ),
    "Year", YEAR( [Date] ),
    "YearNumber", FORMAT( [Date], "YY" ),
    "MonthNumber", FORMAT( [Date], "MM" ),
    "YearMonthNumber", FORMAT( [Date], "YYYY-MM" ),
    "MonthYearName", FORMAT( [Date], "mmm-YYYY" ),
    "YearMonthShort", FORMAT( [Date], "YYYY-mmm" ),
    "MonthNameShort", FORMAT( [Date], "mmm" ),
    "MonthNameLong", FORMAT( [Date], "mmmm" ),
    "WEEKNUM", WEEKNUM( [Date], 2 ),
    "DayOfWeekNumber", 
        IF( 
            WEEKDAY( [Date] ) = 1,
            7,
            WEEKDAY( [Date] ) - 1
        ),
    "DayOfWeek", FORMAT( [Date], "dddd" ),
    "DayOfWeekShort", FORMAT( [Date], "ddd" ),
    "Quarter", "Q" & FORMAT( [Date], "Q" ),
    "YearQuarter", FORMAT( [Date], "YYYY" ) & "/Q" & FORMAT( [Date], "Q" ),
    "DayOfMonth", DAY( [Date] )
)
```

The closest attempt of measures:

```
Call Count Previous Week = 
CALCULATE(
    [Call Count],
    FILTER(
        ALL('Calendar'),
        'Calendar'[Date] = 
            MAXX(
                FILTER(
                    'Calendar', 
                    'Calendar'[Date] <= TODAY() - 1
                ), 
                'Calendar'[Date]
            ) - 7
    )
)

Call Count Two Weeks Prior = 
CALCULATE(
    [Call Count],
    FILTER(
        ALL('Calendar'),
        'Calendar'[Date] = 
            MAXX(
                FILTER(
                    'Calendar', 
                    'Calendar'[Date] <= TODAY() - 1
                ), 
                'Calendar'[Date]
            ) - 14
    )
)
```

However, these 2 measures return values for 2 and 3 weeks ago.

Comment: What is your model and measure so far ?

Comment: Post updated with current measure

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it, with the simplest solution..
I used [Call Count] and filtered the visual for last 7 days, and added the below measure for the 7 days previous to that. I then added a 'DateValue' to my Calendar table, added this new value to the tooltip field and used it for sorting.

```
"DateValue", DATEDIFF( [Date], EndDate, DAY )



Call Count Previous Week = 
CALCULATE(
    [Call Count],
    FILTER(
        ALL('Calendar'),
        'Calendar'[Date] = 
            MAXX(
                FILTER(
                    'Calendar', 
                    'Calendar'[Date] <= TODAY() - 1
                ), 
                'Calendar'[Date]
            ) - 7
    )
)
```